# Want to get all user's products by category including category that have no product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models - parent and child, and parent has_many children, and I have an array of parents and want to retrieve all of the children for all of those parents including parent that have no children. Parent will render as_json and send to react components.

What is the cleanest way to get all categories with current_user's products including categories that have no product associated with them?

I want to view like this:

## Category1

- Product 1
- Product 2

## Category2

- Product 1
- Product 2

## Category3

- (empty)

---

## I already try

```
@categories = Category.includes(:products).where(products: { user_id: current_user.id }) 
@categories.as_json(include: :products)

#Category that has no product is not included
```

## Model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end
```

Comment: You're getting categories by their association with user products, and category3 has no products which mean it has no products associated with the current user and will not be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `as_json` method

```
Category.includes(:products).as_json(user_id: current_user.id)

## model/category.rb
def as_json(options = {})
  json = serializable_hash(options)
  json['products'] = products.where(user_id: options[:user_id]).as_json
  json
end
```